# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in getting google results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I asked in this post [How to get the number of results from google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580064/how-to-get-the-number-of-results-from-google?noredirect=1#comment107183278_60580064) more information on how to get the number of results from google in a date range, but it was closed as duplicate. Unfortunately the two other results that were suggested have not fixed my issues in getting this number. Using the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Google Count.')
parser.add_argument('word', help='word to count')
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                 params={'q':'"'+args.word+'"',
                         "tbs":"li:1"}
                )

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print (soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text)
```

I have found this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        14 
>        15 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
>   ---> 16 print (soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text)
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Also trying with this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search = "manchester"

r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params={'q':search})

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
res = soup.find("div", {"id": "resultStats"})
print (res.text)
print int(res.text.replace(",", "").split()[1])
```

I got the same error.

Do you have any idea on how to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that your call to requests.get returns nothing.
There could be several reasons, most of them network related (no DNS, no web access...).
Can you access that URL via curl on the host where your script is running?
I tried to run this script on my system and Google was not happy. Apparently it is against their terms of services. I think their API is the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I found this code on stackoverflow as my previous question was closed and considered duplicate. I do not know how to get the number of results from a query on Google using Python, so I have been looking for something that could help me with that.

Comment: The problem is not the code. The problem is that Google will not allow you to do things that way. But please feel free to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: I will do it Sam, but since I would need to find also an alternative solution to get those results in a way that does not violate Google terms, I would need to wait for it a bit. The problem has been that stackoverflow closed my question with no answer but just saying the two other questions had the same solutions. However, those solutions have not fixed my issue

Comment: This is probably the best approach:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't specified `user-agent` in HTTP requests `headers`. Learn more about [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) and [request `headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header).

Basically, `user-agent` let identifies the browser, its version number, and its host operating system that representing a person (browser) in a Web context that lets servers and network peers identify if it's a bot or not. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

In this case, you need to send a fake user-agent so Google would treat your request as a "real" user visit.

Pass `user-agent` into request `headers`:

```py
headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get("YOUR_URL", headers=headers)
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Number-of-Total-Search-Results-python-bs4#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "fus ro dah definition",  # query
  "gl": "us",                    # country 
  "hl": "en"                     # language
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search',
                        headers=headers,
                        params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

# .previous_sibling will go to, well, previous sibling removing unwanted part: "(0.38 seconds)"
number_of_results = soup.select_one('#result-stats nobr').previous_sibling
print(number_of_results)

# About 107,000 results
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. it's a paid API with a free plan.

The main difference in your case is that you don't have to deal with selecting selectors to extract data or maintain parser over time since it's already done for the end-user. The only thing that needs to be done is just to get the data you want from the structured JSON.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "fus ro dah defenition",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

result = results["search_information"]['total_results']
print(result)

# 107000
```

P.S - I wrote a blog post about how to scrape [Google Organic Results](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-organic-search-with-python-3hp5).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.